# Transações entre fila e banco de dados

Tags: java, arquitetura-de-software

Pessoal como vocês tratam transações entre filas e bancos de dados ?

Estou com um cenário onde devo fazer o débito (Retirar dinheiro da conta) da conta de um cliente e enviar uma mensagem na fila, mas se por algum motivo a mensagem não for enviada (Timeout ou qualquer coisa do gênero) preciso creditar (Colocar dinheiro na conta) o valor novamente na conta do cliente, sei que posso simplesmente fazer o crédito em caso de falha, mas e se a falha no envio para fila na verdade for uma falha de internet ou coisa assim que não disponibilize também a conexão ao banco de dados impossibilitando que eu desfaça o efeito colateral ?

Caso eu já tiver realizado o debito na conta e não puder creditar pois houve uma falha e minha aplicação ficou isolada do mundo o que posso fazer ?

Há alguma forma diferente de resolver, ao invés de adicionar o método de envio para fila no meio da minha transação SQL, para poder fazer um Rollback se houver esse tipo de falha?

Estou utilizando Spring Boot 2, Java 8, RabbitMQ e SQL Server 2017.

Comment: já usou o `@Transactional`?

Comment: No caso de comunicações assíncronas como filas, talvez uma boa estratégia seja utilizar uma arquitetura de [event sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)

Comment: O único problema com o @Transactional é que não sei se ele tem esse gerenciamento de transações de dois objetos separados (DB e RabbitMQ).

Comment: Event Sourcing é uma ótima arquitetura, mas creio que por sí só não resolva o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Ricardo Pontual está correto. O uso de `@Transactional` pode resolver seu problema. Como o assunto é muito extenso e complexo (e não tenho experiência com este uso de transação), recomendo a leitura de dois artigos sobre este assunto:

- [Dave Syer's article: Distributed transactions in Spring, with and without XA](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html)
- [Using transactions with RabbitMQ and SQL database in Spring Boot application](http://lifeinide.com/post/2017-12-29-spring-boot-rabbitmq-transactions/)

Agora, como você não quer usar transação e está em um cenário onde sua aplicação ficou isolada do mundo, você acaba ficando sem opções.

> e se a falha no envio para fila na verdade for uma falha de internet ou coisa assim que não disponibilize também a conexão ao banco de dados impossibilitando que eu desfaça o efeito colateral ?

Por padrão, o Spring Boot vai ficar tentando enviar a mensagem continuamente até conseguir estabelecer a conexão com o RabbitMQ e conseguir enviar a mensagem. Isto, em teoria, já resolveria para você o seu problema. Só fique atento que acho que existe um limite de tentativas para isto. mas acredito que no Spring Boot este parâmetro esteja configurado para tentar sem limite por padrão. [Consulte a documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html) para ter certeza. Outro problema aqui é que se durante estas novas tentativas a aplicação for reiniciada, você perderá esta mensagem.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta assim que possível testarei essas alternativas e responderei.

Comment: Decidi seguir com o padrão 1PC e checar em toda mensagem se ela já havia sido processada